# Eclipse + Tomcat how to keep the server running

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I'm developing a SOAP client and server and I was trying to use the same eclipse instance for both sides. The two projects are on separate workspaces so I need to switch between them often. Can I deploy the server side to my Tomcat THEN switch to the client side workspace without Eclipse stopping Tomcat? Or do I need to start Tomcat manually and deploy a war?

Comment: Why not simply open two instance of Eclipse ?

Comment: I thought I could spare some memory. I guess if nothing else that works

Comment: use  two instance of Eclipse, It will not eat up your memory, i always work on two instance, one with j2ee and other with core java. not problem it all.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can start Tomcat manually and deploy the war. The other way try to import the client application project to your other workspace.
File->Import->General->Existing project into workspace

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:- Create tomcat instance in your server/ local machine and deploy war file in tomcat instance and start the tomcat.

Option 2:- Import both project in same workspace , and run in two instances of tomcat by creating 2 instance of tomcat in eclipse, make sure to change the port configuration in each instance

http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse